# MissMatching parameters in ajax call, try catch block

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

How to identify mismatching of parameters on a ajax call ? I have the following code sample

```
var driverId = $('#driverId').val();
var driverPhoneNumber =  $('#driverPhoneNumber').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'srvl_def',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        driverId: driverId,
        driverPhoneNumber: driverPhoneNumber
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.mensaje);
    }
});
```

My AJAX calls are much more complex than this. I have close to 80 parameters at some places. Missing a parameter it becomes impossible traceback and its very time consuming. Also when parameters are `undefined` it takes time to debug that. Is there a way in which I can use a `try catch` block to print out all the `undefined` and non matching parameters of my ajax ?

Comment: Do you want to test for undefined parameters before making the ajax call or after the call has failed, using information provided by the server?

Comment: Good question. I think "after" the request has been sent to the server.

Comment: How do you currently know on the client, that something went wrong? I mean, does the server send you a status of `400` or is there some message in the response body?